# How to make pip install python modules in my current python2.7 installation on mac (instead of 2.6)?

Tags: python, macos, pip, macports

I've got a mac on which I installed python using macports. I like it this way because I could manually install numpy, scipy etc. without needing to mess with pre-built packages like enthought. I now wanted to install web.py, but after trying to install it through both easy_install and pip, I can't import it on the interactive python command line.
When installing it, it also says: Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg while it says the following when I type 'python': Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:28) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

When I type 'which python' I get: /opt/local/bin/python

So my question is: how to make easy_install and/or pip install modules in the python installation which I enter when I simply type 'python' on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using macports for python then you should install pip and easy_install via macports as well. You seem to have a non macports pipon your path.

installing py27-pip will give you a pip-2.7 executable script on your path, similarly for easy_install.

The macports version have the python version in their name so as to allow multiple versions of python to be installed. If you want just pip then create a bash alias or link the pip-2.7 script to pip in a directory on yourpath.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I just get an error because I already have a version of pip installed: Error: org.macports.activate for port py27-pip returned: Image error: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port py27-pip. Use 'port -f activate py27-pip' to force the activation. On Linux I normally do sudo apt-get purge pip (or similar), but how do I uninstall the existing pip on OSX?

Comment: Unfortunately you did not install it via macports, hence the ` does not belong to a registered port` just do the force activate which will overwrite it

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. I did 'sudo port -f install py27-pip' and after that a 'sudo pip install web.py' again leads to a "Requirement already satisfied" whereas importing web on the Python interactive command line still gives me an "ImportError: No module named web". Any other ideas?

Comment: try pip2.7 rather than pip

Comment: sudo pip2.7 install  web.py => pip2.7: command not found. I also tried it with pip27 (without the dot) but that gives the same result. Is there no way of completely removing the other pip-package from the command line?

Comment: Sorry should be pip-2.7 as written in my answer

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! One last question. Do you know how I can make it work that using just 'pip' (without the -2.7 behind it) refers to the ports version of pip? I would like to forget about this stuff and not constantly remember that I need to use pip-2.7.. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a bash alias - or a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin from pip or pip-2.7

Comment: Good tips. I created a bash alias like so: alias pip='pip-2.7', ut unfortunately that doesn't work. I now want to create a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin. I know how to create a symbolic link (ln -s [TARGET] [SHORTCUT]), but I don't see any file named pip-2.7 in /usr/local/bin. Do you know what the target should be?

Comment: Yjr target is /usr/local/bin/pip and source the full path to pip-2.7 bvut the alias should have worked

Answer (score 0):

I also do Django development on my Mac, but have found a better solution (which allows easy use of pip) to use Vagrant + VirtualBox + Chef to install Django in a local VM (which would allow you to replicate production server settings). You can then access it on your local browser. There's a really good introduction here:

http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/setup-a-django-vm-with-vagrant-virtualbox-and-chef/

I've updated the vagrantfile provided by the tutorial to use precise32 (to stay compatible with people who may be on 32-bit systems), a newer Ubuntu release, and include emacs, python, and the MySQL client. I hope this helps.

Additional git repos necessary:

```
git clone git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/emacs
git clone git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/python
git clone git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql
```

And the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :djangovm do |django_config|
    # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
    django_config.vm.box = "precise32"

    # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
    # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
    django_config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

    # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
    # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
    django_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
    django_config.vm.forward_port 8000, 8001

    # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path (relative
    # to this Vagrantfile), and adding some recipes and/or roles.
    #
    django_config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
      chef.add_recipe "apt"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_wsgi"
      chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
      chef.add_recipe "git"
      chef.add_recipe "vim"
      chef.add_recipe "emacs"
      chef.add_recipe "python"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql"
    #
    #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
    #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi FlipperPA. Thanks for your tip. I had a look at vagrant, installed it, and tried to fire it up. I ran into some errors and gave up (way to quickly, I know). Main thing is that I would like to use a native solution. But thanks anyway for the tips!